# Jstl taglib error. Jstl not loading html

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Am developing Spring MVC application.
In my jsp page, when i include jstl taglib, its not loading the html page, hence showing the code when i run the application.

Please suggest me any solutions.
Thanks.

result in browser,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>    
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body { padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way
      to the bottom of the topbar */ }
    </style>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $.getJSON('<spring:url value="activities.json"/>', {
                    ajax : 'true'
                }, function(data){
                    var html = '<option value="">--Please select one--</option>';
                    var len = data.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + data[i].desc + '">'
                                + data[i].desc + '</option>';
                    }
                    html += '</option>';

                    $('#activities').html(html);
                });

            });

    </script>
    <style>
        .error {
            color: #ff0000;
        }

        .errorblock {
            color: #000;
            background-color: #ffEEEE;
            border: 3px solid #ff0000;
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 16px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="#">
            <spring:message code="minutes.exercised"/>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h1>
          <spring:message code="minutes.exercised"/>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <a class="btn" href="?language=en">
        English
      </a>
      <a class="btn" href="?language=es">
        Spanish
      </a>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <form:form commandName="exercise">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        <div class="control-group">
          <label for="textinput1">
            <spring:message code="minutes.text"/>
          </label>
          <form:input path="minutes"/>
          <form:errors path="minutes" cssClass="error" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label for="selectinput1">
            <spring:message code="minutes.activity" />
          </label>
          <form:select id="activities" path="activity" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="<spring:message code="minutes.button.enter"/>"/>

    </form:form>

      <span class="label">
        <spring:message code="minutes.goal"/> ${goal.minutes}
      </span>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Maven Dependency`enter code here`


 <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There is no trace of the JSTL in your JSP. You're only using spring tags, and they're not part of the JSTL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have edited my post. After using JSTL taglibe.Still is not working.

Comment: That's not even the right URL for the core taglib. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. And I still don't understand what you're asking: you're not using any JSTL tag in your JSP. This reads a lot like: I want to compile Java code, so I downloaded a C++ compiler and it doesn't work.

Comment: When i run the application at my local host, it output shows the skeleton code and yes i have edited and included <%@taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> , still have problem :(

Comment: Have you read my first comment? You're not using the JSTL; You're using spring tags. The JSTL is irrelevant.